# Show the data points on top of the curve in MATLAB plotting?

Tags: matlab, plot

I plotted a series of points into a curve using MATLAB as follows.

```
x = [1 4 6 8 0 2 4 7 8]
plot(x, 'blue')
```

I now wish to show those points on top of the curve. I have tried

```
x = [1 4 6 8 0 2 4 7 8]
plot(x, '.blue')
```

but that is not what I want, as I want the curve to be still solid and the dots show the data on the curve.

How may I do that?

Comment: use '.-blue' instead. the '-' means draw a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the [`linespec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html) string a specification for the line `'-'` as well

```
 plot( x, '.-b' );
```

Comment: You might want to try something larger than dots when drowing a solid line, `plot( x, 's-b')` might be better